# swift get directions in maps app

Tags: swift, maps, directions

I have an app that displays multiple locations in multiple mapviews. How can I add a button that allows the user to open one of these locations in their maps app and to get directions to it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you got an `MKPlaceMark` you can use an `MKMapItem` and open the Map-app with the location as `launchOption`:

```
var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: yourPlaceMark)

mapItem.name = "The way I want to go"

//You could also choose: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking
var launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]

mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

**Swift 3**

```
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
```

Comment: sorry, I am new to this... :)